# How to show unique data on my table using php?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Using this code:

```
<?php $contacts = Group::where('account_id','=', Auth::user()->account->account_id)->get(); ?>
      @if ( count( $data['contacts'] ) > 0 )
        @foreach( $data['contacts'] as $contact )
        <tr>
        <?php $ucontact = \App\User::find($contact->user_id)?>
            <td>{{$ucontact->group->account_name}}</td>
            <td>{{$contact->event_name}}</td>
        @endforeach
      @else
```

Helps me show the data on my table. The problem is it shows duplicate datas. Is it possible to show only the unique ones?
Like for example:

> Account Name Event Name
> Account 1   Event 1
> Account 2   Event 2
> Account 1   Event 3

Account 1 is shown twice. I need to hide the duplicating data on my table.

Comment: Use DISTINCT. but what you shown output is more correct, because if an account is related to more activity then it have to show all one, because if an account involve in more activity and you show only one then it will lead to ambiguity and future errors

Comment: @Anant is right. But when you can't alter the query for what reason. array_unique could help you out see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: A better way is to show comma separated events for same id's

Comment: why dont you use group by on account_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by account_id`:-

```
Group::where('account_id','=', Auth::user()->account->account_id)->groupBy('account_id')->get()
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
$contacts->unique( array('account_name','event_name') );
```

Comment: I used the groupBy but still I thank you for answering. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add group by clause in your query.

Here is the sample code.

```
<?php
$contacts = Group::where('account_id', Auth::user()->account->account_id)->groupBy('account_id')->get();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much